# On PostgreSQL, how to type commands?

Tags: database, postgresql

On Postgresql, I needed to copy databases from a server to another. I see the solutions use commands like:

```
pg_dump -C -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname | psql -h localhost -U localuser dbname
```

But.. where do I need to type these commands?

Comment: I would say command line... You may of course write this in a batch file and execute the batch.

Comment: Those are command line programs. You type them in - well - the commandline

Comment: I would have guessed it's command lines, but I tried of course. Neither the windows command line recognize this command (and no one ever wrote in the examples any call to another program, nor set a path to this command), neither the pg_admin console. In the later, I have no error message, but simply nothing happens.

Comment: If the programs are not found, then you did not setup your `PATH` correctly.Simply change directly into the `bin` directory of your Postgres installation and run them from there if you don't wan to change your `PATH`. That has nothing to do with Postgres. Running command line program is basic operating system knowledge. If you don't know how to change your `PATH` search for "*setup path windows*" I'm pretty sure there are gazillions of examples for that

Comment: Thank you. The confusion comes from the fact that there is a console in pgsql, but also scripts and queries. It was not so obvious for me, that it's in the command lines of windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that not in a single step ... I like it to have more control about such kind of processes.

You need to open a terminal window and then type the commands.

```
pg_dump -C --column_inserts -U remoteuser -h remotehost > my_backup.sql

# copy the file to the server you want

# change the desired parameter like the database name
nano my_baskup.sql

createdb -U newuser -h localhost newdb_name
psql -U newuser -h localhost postgres < my_backup.sql
```

If the copy to other databases in postgresql is sometimes tricky imo this is the most robust way

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]    
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.    
C:\Users\xxxxx>pg_dump    
'pg_dump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.